# visibility of a layout in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, visibility

I got a layout that i want to make visible (which was "GONE" first) on clicking a button.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/registration_layout"
    layout="@layout/user_registration"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<include
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    layout="@layout/login"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Here is what i include in the xml file

```
fun onClickLogin(view: View) {
    val login_layout = R.id.login_layout as Layout
    val registration_layout = R.id.login_layout as Layout
    login_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val btn_login = R.id.registration as Button
    val btn_registration = R.id.registration as Button
    btn_login.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

In my kotlin file, the visibility for the button is working but not for the layout... Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: review your code again
``` val login_layout = R.id.login_layout as Layout
    val registration_layout = R.id.login_layout as Layout
```
the registration_layout  val and login_layout val has the same reference xml ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of casting to `Layout`, cast layout to `View`:

```
fun onClickLogin(view: View) {
    val login_layout = R.id.login_layout as View //note : from import android.view.View
    val registration_layout = R.id.registration_layout as View //note: you wrote R.id.login_layout
    login_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    registration_layout.visibility = View.GONE

    val btn_login = R.id.btn_login as Button
    val btn_registration = R.id.registration as Button
    btn_login.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    btn_registration = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: But now on clicking the button the app crash and I cannot figure why...

Comment: @Malopieds Do you cast layout as `View`?

Comment: just replace it by  `val loginLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.login_layout)` and it worked thanks!